# invoke command cannot open browser on local or remote computer with latest version of chromedriver 93

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I am currently experiencing a batch script problem using the `Invoke-Command` command on a remote machine. The script in question allows me to launch a web page and retrieve information. Everything was working since the chrome update.
By running PowerShell, I can see that the `chromedriver.exe` process is running but nothing is happening.
I did the test locally and the same result.

Here is the PowerShell script:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'remoteserver' -ScriptBlock {cmd /c 'D:\...\..\ScrapingScript.bat param1 param2'}
```

Logically, by executing it, I have the browser which opens and then closes when it has finished. While now nothing.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: review permissions of your account on remote server

Comment: @user2956477 unfortunately that no solved the problem. the account permission has been tested as admin.
Otherwise, when i execute the script with the acccount on the server directly, chromedriver is launched and chrome browser is opennig with blank page

Comment: what is a content of `ScrapingScript.bat` ?

Comment: Here is the content: